# Get non-masked values in Numpys Masked arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, data-science, masked-array

I'm trying to extract data from netCDF4 files. These contain "MaskedArrays" which are part of the Numpy library.

My Data contains: *latitude*, *longitude*, *day* and *values* (separated over different files).
Additionally a mask which shows, which latitude/longitudes are not valid for various reasons (no measurements, or other reasons).

My data looks like this (for masked data):

```
masked_array(
    data =
     [[[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
        ..., 
       [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]]],
    mask =
     [[[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
        ...,
       [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]]],
    fill_value = 32767)
```

I'm searching for a numpy method (or similar), which can extract only these values which are not masked. Ideally just by cutting all non-valid entries out of the dataset.
I found `.compressed`, but it gives a one dimensional array back. From the 3rd dimension this is quite a loss of information as I don't know, where these values are.

Additionally I tried `nonzero = the_array['one of the values'][0].nonzero()`. 
This gives me a double array with lat/lon values, but after that I still have to access these - which is slow. Unfortunately after knowing how to access all this date I need to do that on 30*6 files each with ~1500×700×365 datapoints :D.

```
all_days = [(x, rhstmax['stuff'][x][24][1288]) for x in range(366)]
# represents just for lat:24,lon:1288 all days. First 20:
all_days[:20] =
    [(0, 15.799999),
     (1, 16.199999),
     (2, 17.4),
     (3, 13.2),
     (4, 10.8),
     (5, 11.3),
     (6, 15.299999),
     (7, 16.299999),
     (8, 14.099999),
     (9, 10.8),
     (10, 9.5),
     (11, 9.0999994),
     (12, 11.9),
     (13, 9.1999998),
     (14, 31.0),
     (15, 49.0),
     (16, 8.6999998),
     (17, 10.0),
     (18, 44.099998),
     (19, 30.699999)]
# ... takes forever :(
```

Comment: Ideally, what would be the structure of your output after cutting all non-valid entries?  Have you checked this overview on [Accessing only the valid entries](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#accessing-only-the-valid-entries)?

Comment: compressed returns 1d because the number values per row or column isn't consistent.  fill is another way of 'removing' the masked values.

Answer (score 6):

To get the non-masked data in Python you can use the `.mask` tool

Suppose you have the following dataset:

```
data = [[0.0 1.0 -- --]
       [2.0 3.0 -- --]]
```

You can obtain the non-masked data while getting all the indices which are `False` by the `data.mask` command.

```
data = data[data.mask == False]
```

Note that this will give you 1D-array of all the input

```
data -> [0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove rows that have any/all masked data:

```
data = data[~data.mask.any(axis=1)]
```